# How do I modify the default docker "rails server" command to use https?

Tags: ruby, docker

I have successfully setup the official Redmine project management server in a docker container. It uses Ruby on rails, I think. Now I want to implement HTTPS with a custom certificate.

The default command of the docker image is `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`. This starts a server on port 3000, using the http protocol.

I want to modify this command so it uses https. I presume it is possible, and I found something [here](https://madeintandem.com/blog/rails-local-development-https-using-self-signed-ssl-certificate/), which says to use `rails s -b 'ssl://localhost:3000?key=path/to/file/localhost.key&cert=path/to/file/localhost.crt'`.

This however does not work for me, it always prepends http and the port 3000, which makes the command invalid.

I also tried to modify the config.ru file to contain this, according to the docs:

```
#https support
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/redmine.cer'
pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new File.read '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/redmine.pem'

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3001,
                                 :SSLEnable => true,
                                 :SSLCertificate => cert,
                                 :SSLPrivateKey => pkey)

#default
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application
```

This works, but it creates a whole new server. So I somehow have the default server on port 3000, and this one on port 3001.

How do I modify the docker command to only run one server, with https? Which config files do I have to change? I've been trying for hours. Thanks!

Comment: What does your Dockerfile look like?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but the best practice is not to have the Rails server manage SSL but instead to use a reverse proxy with something like nginx handling SSL termination. Unless you're certain you have one of the narrow edge cases where Rails should handle SSL, I'd suggest looking into what I've described above.

Comment: My Dockerfile is minimal, just a FROM redmine and COPY certificates to some path.

As for the extra server, I would prefer to keep it simple. My solution will only be visible on the internal network, and I mostly want https so it look more professional.